# box with margin on full width of window

Tags: html, css

I have problem with simple layout. It should look like this:

[image: SS]

my code look like:

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
 }
#black{
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#grey{
  background: grey;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 2em;
 }
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="black">
    <p>something</p>
    <div id="grey">
      <p>2#something</p>
    </div>
  </div>
 </body>
```

Unfortunately this way is wrong because a scrollbar appears. I need a responsive solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't set a width on `#grey`, and remove the right margin:

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
 }
#black{
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#grey{
  background: grey;
  margin: 2em;
  margin-right:0;
 }
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="black">
    <p>something</p>
    <div id="grey">
      <p>2#something</p>
    </div>
  </div>
 </body>
```

Since `#grey` is a div, and is a block element by default, it will fill the available space.